# execvp to sort contents

Tags: c, unix, exec, execvp

I'm trying to sort a file using execvp and here's my code.

```
char *argv1[]={ "sh", "-c", "sort input.txt > output.txt", NULL };
```

The problem is this command sorts the contents in output file but I want sorting only on terminal output.

Comment: Well don't redirect it to an output file then.

Comment: Simply don't redirect the output!

Comment: Why don't you simply use `system()` instead of `fork()`/`exec`?

Answer (score 0):

to get the output on the terminal rather than into a file use:

```
system{ "sort input.txt" );
```

And do not use some expensive thing like `execvp()`.  The above line does the whole job

Answer (score 0):

You could refer the example of [Using cat and execvp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119440/using-cat-and-execvp/44927499#44927499)

Replace with below code.

```
char *cmd1[] = { "sort", "input.txt", 0 };
char *cmd2[] = { "tee", "output.txt", 0 };
```